# Modify an Image based on another architecture

Tags: architecture, containers, virtualization

I would like to modify an image (arm64) from within a host which is based on another architecture, like x86.

To be more specific: The image I would like to modify is the pre-installed Ubuntu arm64 image.

My current way of doing the above, i.e. preinstalling new software, is based on another topic here on SO, which is:

- install qemu-user-static on host
- copy qemu-aarch64-static to the arm64 bin directory
- run sth via chroot and the copied emulator

Unfortunately it gets complicated as soon as you are running e.g. Apt from within a bash -c command. It looks like you would need the binfmt-support within the chroot

This problem feels very basic to me, so I wonder if there is maybe another way for modifying such an image under the  given circumstances. Maybe using sth. like qemu-system and docker?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an awesome article describing a way using systemd-nspawn and qemu-user-static, see here: https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2016-02-07-systemd-nspawn-for-fun-and-wel/

To take it short:

1. Install `qemu-user-static` on host
2. Mount the arm64 image using `losetup` (both, `\` and `\boot\`)
3. `systemd-nspawn` into the mounted root and run whatever you need